# Updating a react-native-map with new coordinates

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a react-native-map inside my application, I'm using it to display fixture information with a flatlist scrolling view overlaid on top of the map;

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import {Dimensions } from "react-native";
import styles from './team.styles.js';

const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');
const Fixtures = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);


  function chkValue(val) {
    return state.region.longitude = val;
  }

  state = { 
    region: {
     latitude: 52.93877,
     longitude: -1.201258,
     latitudeDelta: 0.015,
     longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
  }
 }

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/schimperdigital.com/assets/derbyfutsalclub/fixtureinfo.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setData(json)
      })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);

return (
  <View style={stylesB.container} >
       <MapView
        style={stylesB.map}
        initialRegion={this.state.region}
        >
      <Marker 
        coordinate={{ latitude: 52.93877, longitude:-1.201258 }} 
        image={require("./derbymarker.png")}
      />
      </MapView>
    <View style={stylesB.containerlower}>
      <View>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => chkValue('53.448527')}>
            <View style={styles.containerfixturedetails}>
              <View style={styles.factscontainer}>
                <View style={styles.factscontainerupper}>
                  <Text style={styles.kickofftime}>KO{"\n"}{item.KOTime}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.playerprofilename}>vs {item.Opposition}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.fixturecontainerlower}>
                  <Text style={styles.fixturestats}>TEAM: {item.Team}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.fixturestats}>ADDRESS: {item.LocationAddress}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.fixturestats}>ADMISSION: {item.Admission}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.playerprofileimgcontainer}>

              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      )}
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
)
};

const stylesB = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: dimensions.height,
    width: dimensions.width, 
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerlower: {
    height:300,
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom:20,
  },
 });

export default Fixtures;
```

The map loads, the flatlist pulls back the json file. Where I am struggling is handling the TouchableOpacity onPress. I've tried a couple of ways to address this, but nothing appears to be working :(.

What I want to do is when a user clicks or scrolls the flatlist item that it then passes in its longitude and latitudes data (this is in the JSON that is returned in the flatlist) into the map and the map updates to the new coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, if you use a functional component, you cannot declare the state in the conventional way as if you were using a class component. You also cannot declare "this" as you did to declare the initialRegion.
- From what I can see in your snippet, you are convincing hooks with conventional state handling. You must decide on one of the options, not both.
- In order to update the new coordinates on the map, you need to make a state change.